# Rotate only background image with css or jquery

Tags: css

I have following tags:

[image]

```
<div class="outer-img">
   <div class="inner-circle">
     <image src..../>
   </div>
</div>
```

and I want rotate only the outer `div` on mouse spin all side, image will be follow mouse, please help me.

Comment: you don't have an `outer-div` element, do you mean `outer-img`? You should also post your existing CSS so that people can see how you built the circle in your image.

Comment: Somebody else incorrectly edited it to say `outer-div` instead of "outer div". I've re-edited.

Answer (score 3):

You simply rotate the inner `div` element the opposite way. If you're rotating your outer `div` element by `90deg`, simply apply a rotation of `-90deg` to your inner `div` at the same time.

In the below demo I've added a red top border to the `.outer-img` element and a blue bottom border to the `.inner-circle` element to show that the `.outer-img` rotates whilst the `.inner-circle` appears to stay in the same place.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.outer-img {
  border-top: 1px solid #f00;
}

.inner-circle {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00f;
}

.outer-img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

.outer-img:hover .inner-circle {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-img">
   <div class="inner-circle">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've done the same as I was *doing*, although I stopped since I re-read the part *image will be follow mouse* - in my mind, they're asking *how can i make the blue bit follow the mouse*, which makes this question 100x harder.

Comment: okey it's good thing, real good idea rotare 90 deg outer and rotate -90 iner, ofter this i need continue rotation.. along the mouse spin and what can i do i need like this but...    from {-'moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);}'